# Why fabric.js export is not the same size as the canvas size?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a 1500x1500 canvas with `Fabric.js`. On the inspector I can see a 1500x1500 canvas but also a 750x750 canvas.

[image]

Then, when I run:

```
        canvas.toDataURL({
            format: 'png'
        })
```

The returned image has a resolution of 750x750. Shouldn't it be a 1500x1500 image? I tried to compensate it by scaling the returned image but the ratio between 1500 and 750 changes with different devices.

What am I missing? It makes no difference if a set the width and height of the canvas on the constructor or after creating it with `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`.